# Instagram widget invalid return

Tags: php, instagram

I want to show Instagram photos on my website, using PHP7.
I have registered my app, and added the clientId  and secretId from Instagram. But code below gives me the errors: data is aof non object and foreach is an invalid arguement.

```
<?php
    // Supply a user id and an access token
    $clientid = "my client id";
    $accessToken = "my client secret";

    // Gets our data
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }

    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$clientid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}");
    $result = json_decode($result);
?>



    <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: var dump $result. what is it?

Comment: vardump returns null

Comment: You should maybe consider using this package? https://github.com/vinkla/instagram

Comment: So the request failed. look at what curl_error() gives you

Comment: curl error gives me nothing

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this api for self not for any other users.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Refer this -
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: for the your own access token, this works perfectly fine, can you elaborate more, what exactly didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, you have only `Client ID` & `Client Secret` only, But you don't have `Access Token`.

Follow my steps

first, you have to create `access_token` with your **Client ID** & **Client Secret**

Visit one of the following websites to make `access_token`

- https://elfsight.com/service/generate-instagram-access-token/
- https://rudrastyh.com/tools/access-token

or you can login to the `instagram` account and make your `access_token`

after created the access_token it will be like this format :

`xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Then, add following code in your controller function

```
$access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // your access_token will be this format
$count_feed = 2; // how many feed want to load

$requestURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token='.$access_token.'&count='.$count_feed;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(        
    CURLOPT_URL => $requestURL,
    CURLOPT_HEADER  => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$insta_feeds = json_decode($json_response, true);

_e($insta_feeds); // $insta_feeds['data'] will return feed
```

You can get the feed by using the Instagram library. check out the library here : https://github.com/suhindra/CodeIgniter-Instagram-API